# What computer history museums need hardware donations?

Tags: mac, history, powerpc

I have a "TAM" ([Twentieth Anniversary Macintosh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twentieth_Anniversary_Macintosh)), that I would like to donate to a museum. (As far as I know, this is the first all-in-one flatscreen desktop...)

The Computer History Museum already has several, so I think I would need to find another location.

Does anyone know of any other places that exhibits computer hardware that might be interested?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest [DigiBarn](http://www.digibarn.com/) in Boulder Creek, CA - they have a lot of very cool historical Apple stuff but are always glad of more, I expect.